# How to select the nth element with same classname in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, class, css-selectors

This is the HTML output:

```
<ul class="slides row">
    <li id="t64" class="span3"></li>
    <li id="t65" class="span3"></li>
    <li id="t67" class="span3"></li>
    <li class="detailView desktopView"></li>
    <li id="t66" class="span3"></li>
    <li id="t68" class="span3"></li>
    <li class="detailView desktopView"></li>
    <li class="detailView mobileView"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to select the nth element with the classname `.span3` only.
So I tried this:

```
var targetSlide = 3;
$(".slides").children('.span3:eq('+ targetSlide +')').addClass('on');
```

or

```
var targetSlide = 4;
$(".slides").children('.span3:nth-child('+ targetSlide +')').addClass('on');
```

In both cases `.detailView` is selected. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
var targetSlide= 3;

$('.slides').find('.span3').eq(targetSlide).addClass('on');

// or this syntax does the exact same thing

$('.slides').find('.span3:eq('+targetSlide+')').addClass('on');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this too,

```
var targetSlide = 3;
$(".slides").children('.span3').filter(':eq('+ targetSlide +')').addClass('on');
```

Comment: I resisted to post this example for concern over simplicity but +1 for showing the flexibility of jQuery

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Learners like me needs encouragement like this.!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var targetSlide = 3;
$('.slides').find('.span3').eq(targetSlide).addClass('on');
```